# matching html tag using regex in python

Tags: python, html, regex

```
str="<p class=\"drug-subtitle\"><b>Generic Name:</b> albuterol inhalation (al BYOO ter all)<br><b>Brand Names:</b> <i>Accuneb, ProAir HFA, Proventil, Proventil HFA, ReliOn Ventolin HFA, Ventolin HFA</i></p>"

br=re.match("<p> class=\"drug-subtitle\"[^>]*>(.*?)</p>",str)
```

br returns None

what is the error in the regular expression i have used?

Comment: Do not use regex. Go through the DOM

Comment: i have no idea about DOM.can you mention the error in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you got the input:

```
'<p class="drug-subtitle"><b>Generic Name:</b> albuterol inhalation (al BYOO ter all)<br><b>Brand Names:</b> <i>Accuneb, ProAir HFA, Proventil, Proventil HFA, ReliOn Ventolin HFA, Ventolin HFA</i></p>'
```

and you want to check if :

```
<p class="drug-subtitle"> .. some items here .. </p>
```

exists in your input, the regex to be used is:

```
\<p\sclass=\"drug-subtitle\"[^>]*>(.*?)\<\/p\>
```

description:

```
\< matches the character < literally
p matches the character p literally (case sensitive)
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
class= matches the characters class= literally (case sensitive)
\" matches the character " literally
drug-subtitle matches the characters drug-subtitle literally (case sensitive)
\" matches the character " literally
[^>]* match a single character not present in the list below
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
               giving back as needed.
    > a single character in the list &gt; literally (case sensitive)
> matches the character > literally
1st Capturing group (.*?)
    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible,
                    expanding as needed.
\< matches the character < literally
\/ matches the character / literally
p matches the character p literally (case sensitive)
\> matches the character > literally
```

so the problems in your regex are:

1. in < p> there should be no ">".
2. in < /p> you should escape the "<, / , >"  characters by adding "\" before them.

hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

The fixed regex will be this one. Check the second line at where I have pointed and you'll find where it didn't work for you. I used `findall()` for easy access to all the matched group on my screen.

```
print re.findall('<p class="drug-subtitle"[^>]*>(.*?)</p>',input)
                    ^ you had a > character here
```

But, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) will be easy option for this kind of actions:

```
input='''
<p class="drug-subtitle"><b>Generic Name:</b> albuterol inhalation (al BYOO ter all)<br><b>Brand Names:</b> <i>Accuneb, ProAir HFA, Proventil, Proventil HFA, ReliOn Ventolin HFA, Ventolin HFA</i></p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(input)
br = soup.find("p", {"class": "drug-subtitle"})
print str(br)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really *highly recommend* you use a **DOM Parser** library such as [lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) along with for example [cssselect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect) to do this.

**Example:**

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> html = """<p class="drug-subtitle"><b>Generic Name:</b> albuterol inhalation (al BYOO ter all)<br><b>Brand Names:</b> <i>Accuneb, ProAir HFA, Proventil, Proventil HFA, ReliOn Ventolin HFA, Ventolin HFA</i></p>"""
>>> doc = fromstring(html)
>>> "".join(filter(None, (e.text for e in doc.cssselect(".drug-subtitle")[0])))
'Generic Name:Brand Names:Accuneb, ProAir HFA, Proventil, Proventil HFA, ReliOn Ventolin HFA, Ventolin HFA'
```